# How many reputation did I spend on bounties?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, profile-page, users

Is it possible to know how many reputation I spent on bounties?

Example: Let's say one user spent 50 reputation on one bounty, 150 on the second and 500 on the third. The total would be: 50 + 150 + 500 = 700.

Comment: No need for a query: [*"12 Offered bounties for 1,350 reputation"*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3809375/bpl?tab=bounties&sort=offered)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your profile -> Activity -> bounties -> offered and you'll see how many reputation you spent on bounties:

[image]